# Can curved spacetime be detected by an experiment at home?

Tags: gravity, spacetime, home-experiment, qft-in-curved-spacetime, gravitational-wave-detectors

Can curved spacetime be detected by an experiment at home? I am an educator and trying to find out experiments that can be used to prove curved spacetime, perhaps by reverse engineering any of the effects of curved spacetime or something like that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could observe some effects of spacetime curvature with a telescope. You might have to wait a while for a 1919-like eclipse.

Comment: Presumably you don't mean 'hold a ball out and drop it' because this doesn't surprise, but it *is* the most prominent effect in day to to day life.

Comment: Another telescope type experiment would be measurement of precession of Mercury's perihelion.

Answer (score 2):

As dmckee says in a comment, the most prominent effect of curved spacetime is that geodesics in spacetime correspond to curved paths in space.  So when you toss a ball near Earth's surface and it goes in a downward-curving parabola rather than a straight line, that's due to spacetime curvature.

However, by itself that's not slam-dunk evidence for curved spacetime: the central insight that led to general relativity was that you *also* get curved paths if you're in an accelerating reference frame in a flat spacetime.

The unique feature of a curved spacetime in general relativity, which distinguishes curved spacetime from an accelerated reference frame, is [tidal stretching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_force).  In order for tidal forces to be strong, you have to have both a strong gravitational force and an extended system whose size is comparable to the distance between you and the source.  You're too short to feel Earth tides on anything that would fit inside of your house, and the same is true for lunar tides.  But lunar tides do have an interesting and well-documented effect on the Earth-wide ocean.

If you're interested in a temporal approach, [here's a great letter to *Physics Today*](http://www.leapsecond.com/great2005/) from an atomic-clock collector who used gravitational time dilation on a mountaintop to spend an extra 22 nanoseconds with his family during a camping trip.